# Run a server and local wireless network off my laptop with no internet

Tags: web-server, wifi

I'm trying to run a wireless network from my computer so that people in range can connect to the network and hit a website running off my machine. I don't want to enable file sharing or remote access or anything else of that nature. I just want them to be able to connect to the network, type in an IP or domain name in a browser, and be taken to a locally hosted website. No broader internet access needed.  Any ideas / links to good tutorials on the subject? Is this something i can achieve with just a wifi card or will need a router?

Answer (score 0):

What you have just described is an ["ad-hoc" wireless network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network). Assuming your OS and wireless adaptor's drivers support this you can create an ad-hoc network without needing a wireless access point or other router. When other machines connect to the network they should be able to see your machine if it has a fixed address.

[This page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx) has notes for Windows XP, which should be easy to translate for other Windows variants.